# v-play installation - Cant deploy on desktop and device

Tags: qt, installation, v-play

I’ve just installed v-play but when i compile to desktop i get error :-1: error: cannot find -lGL and exits.

Then if i compile to android it will compile and install but the it never successfully opens the app and it exits on deployment.

These are the warnings i get :

Warnings while parsing QML type information of /home/theguy/V-Play/5.5/android_armv5/qml/QtCanvas3D:

/home/theguy/V-Play/5.5/android_armv5/qml/QtCanvas3D/plugins.qmltypes:1:24: Reading only version 1.1 parts.

/home/theguy/V-Play/5.5/android_armv5/qml/QtCanvas3D/plugins.qmltypes:10:5: Expected only Component and ModuleApi object definitions.

Warnings while parsing QML type information of /home/theguy/V-Play/5.5/gcc_64/qml/QtWebSockets:

/home/theguy/V-Play/5.5/gcc_64/qml/QtWebSockets/plugins.qmltypes:1:24: Reading only version 1.1 parts.

/home/theguy/V-Play/5.5/gcc_64/qml/QtWebSockets/plugins.qmltypes:10:5: Expected only Component and ModuleApi object definitions.

Warnings while parsing QML type information of /home/theguy/V-Play/5.5/gcc_64/qml/QtCanvas3D:

/home/theguy/V-Play/5.5/gcc_64/qml/QtCanvas3D/plugins.qmltypes:1:24: Reading only version 1.1 parts.

/home/theguy/V-Play/5.5/gcc_64/qml/QtCanvas3D/plugins.qmltypes:10:5: Expected only Component and ModuleApi object definitions.

And these are the compile issues I get:

15:03:42: Packaging error: Command “/home/theguy/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s 9cc172fdedea pull /system/bin/sh: readlink: not found /home/theguy/Desktop/Projects/v-play/ConverseLanguages/build-ConverseLanguages-Android_for_armeabi_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_5_0-Release/app_process” failed.Exit code: 1

15:03:42: Package deploy: Failed to pull “/system/bin/sh: readlink: not found” to “/home/theguy/Desktop/Projects/v-play/ConverseLanguages/build-ConverseLanguages-Android_for_armeabi_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_5_0-Release/app_process”.

15:03:42: Package deploy: Running command “/home/theguy/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s 9cc172fdedea pull /system/lib/libc.so /home/theguy/Desktop/Projects/v-play/ConverseLanguages/build-ConverseLanguages-Android_for_armeabi_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_5_0-Release/libc.so”.

Error while building/deploying project ConverseLanguages (kit: Android for armeabi (GCC 4.9, Qt 5.5.0))

When executing step “Deploy to Android device”

Answer (score 1):

please see here for a reply: https://v-play.net/developers/forums/t/installation-problem-error-cannot-find-lgl/

Cheers, Chris